# "Unresolved Reference To Built In Type" errors on basic SQL data types

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project

My database projects in Visual Studio have recently starting throwing these unresolved reference errors every time any `create table` file in the project is touched.

```
SQL71501: Column: ___ has an unresolved reference to Built-in Type [int].
SQL71501: Column: ___ has an unresolved reference to Built-in Type [datetime].
SQL71501: Column: ___ has an unresolved reference to Built-in Type [varchar].
```

If I rebuild the project, everything builds with no errors, and the errors flagged by Visual Studio disappear. However, as soon as I edit any file (even as little as adding a space to the end of a file), that file will immediately become plagued with these unresolved reference errors... *until I rebuild again*. However, as it's a fairly large project, I don't want to spend about a minute rebuilding after every single minor edit.

This project is worked on by several other people, who do not encounter this issue. How can I resolve this?

---

Update: If I change tabs, the errors for the first tab disappear until I go back to it. I've also disabled all extensions, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Does your views/SPs  reference the tables using this naming convention ( 3 parts qualified name ) ?

'DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName'

Comment: Sorry, didn't clarify it correctly - it's the `create table` scripts specifically that do it. Those are written `create table [schema].[table] ( ... )`

Comment: This is just an educated guess , please check the custom type's file properties in VS and make sure Build Action is set to Build.

Comment: @DeJaVo, thank you! That was the fix for me. Never would have thought of that as something to check.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Close down Visual Studio, navigate to the project folder and find the `.dbmdl` file. **Delete it**. Reopen the project and rebuild it. This should solve the problem.

Comment: The issue keeps coming back though. Hopefully one day we can track down the source of the corruption (multiple open VS instances perhaps?).

Comment: I'm having this issue recur sometimes multiple times a day, without using multiple VS instances. This is also after performing a *full repair* on VS. I'm  using VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the solution was to change the target of my SSDT project to a more recent version of SQL Server (right click on the projet/Properties/Project Settings/Target platform).

See: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565459/FixingplusSSDTplusunresolvedplusreferenceplustoplu

Comment: Just to add to this, to find out which version of SQL Server I was running, I ran `SELECT @@VERSION` against the database.

Comment: Thanks for this specification.